# How to include code coverage for bats in a GitLab yaml?

Tags: bash, gitlab, code-coverage, self-hosting, bats-core

### Context

After setting up a working GitLab yaml for bats (Bash Automated Testing System) using an Alpine docker image:

```yaml
unit_test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - apk update && apk add bash
        - apk add git # Default docker image uses Alpine iso Ubuntu, hence apk.
        - chmod +x *.sh
        - ./install-bats-libs.sh
        - bash ./test.sh
```

I noticed it would be marvellous to include [code coverage](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core/issues/15). However [most](https://about.codecov.io/blog/how-to-get-coverage-metrics-for-bash-scripts/) [of](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash) the [examples](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/11/27/go-tools-and-gitlab-how-to-do-continuous-integration-like-a-boss/) are for Travis or rely on an external server. I did not yet find a GitLab example for self-hosted code coverage for Bash.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask: *How can one include a self-hosted bash code coverage report in a `.GitLab-ci.yml`?*

### Attempt

The comment by Benjamin W. led me to [this](https://github.com/fengb/hostcamo/blob/dc49c9fad8cdf4c6bef857d72bf454bd83e63bf3/.gitlab-ci.yml) example. Based on that example, I tried the following BashCov in the following GitLab.yml on [this bats shell testing repository](https://github.com/a-t-0/shell_unit_testing_template):

```
stages:
  - test
  - coverage_test

unit_test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - apk update && apk add bash
        - apk add git # Default docker image uses Alpine iso Ubuntu, hence apk.
        - chmod +x *.sh
        - ./install-bats-libs.sh
        - bash ./test.sh


test:
  stage: coverage_test
  image: ruby:slim
  before_script:
    - gem install bashcov
  script:
    # bashcov cannot run as root so here's a magic user
    - useradd -s /bin/bash user
    - su user -c "$(command -v bashcov) gem install git && ./install-bats-libs.sh && ./test.sh"
  coverage: '/\(\d+\.\d+%\) covered/'
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
```

That passes the BATS tests, however the second job, with the coverage fails with output:

### Output

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.4.0 (43b2dc3d)
  on trucolrunner Pa3Jpz_s
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:06
Using Docker executor with image ruby:slim ...
Pulling docker image ruby:slim ...
Using docker image sha256:a1ed21c1d9c7a0d7dbc9d24a25d55ee51e9d798d01073b75051dc8792e313644 for ruby:slim with digest ruby@sha256:2fd51ded2c105603ad42099bc60a057ec93667a8ebefab75b780ea1d57efa517 ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-pa3jpzs-project-116-concurrent-0 via pcname...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/shell_unit_testing_template/.git/
Checking out 90204537 as main...
warning: unable to rmdir 'test/libs/bats': Directory not empty
warning: unable to rmdir 'test/libs/bats-assert': Directory not empty
warning: unable to rmdir 'test/libs/bats-support': Directory not empty
Removing test/libs/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:03
Using docker image sha256:a1ed21c1d9c7a0d7dbc9d24a25d55ee51e9d798d01073b75051dc8792e313644 for ruby:slim with digest ruby@sha256:2fd51ded2c105603ad42099bc60a057ec93667a8ebefab75b780ea1d57efa517 ...
$ gem install bashcov
Successfully installed simplecov-html-0.10.2
Successfully installed docile-1.1.5
Successfully installed simplecov-0.15.1
Successfully installed bashcov-1.8.2
4 gems installed
$ useradd -s /bin/bash user
$ su user -c "$(command -v bashcov) gem install git && ./install-bats-libs.sh && ./test.sh"
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 8: require: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 9: require: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 10: require: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 12: required_version: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 14: unless: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 15: abort: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 16: end: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 18: args: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 20: begin: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 21: Gem::GemRunner.new.run: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 22: rescue: command not found
/usr/local/bin/gem: line 23: exit: e.exit_code: numeric argument required
Run completed using bashcov 1.8.2 with Bash 5.1, Ruby 3.1.2, and SimpleCov 0.15.1.
Coverage report generated for /bin/bash gem install git to /builds/root/shell_unit_testing_template/coverage. 0 / 649 LOC (0.0%) covered.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: If you have Ruby in your container, you could use [bashcov](https://github.com/infertux/bashcov).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you! I included an attempt on including Bashcov in the `.GitLab-CI.yml`. It was not quite successful yet, though I'll work on it.

Comment: @a.t. Did you wind up getting this to work? I'm wondering the same. If you did, you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Cliff thank you for your inquiry, I did not yet get to solving this.